# Open Browser (IE), when no app for specific URI is installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, uri

It's my first WP8-project and I honestly googled for hours and couln't find any answer for this specific question.

When the user hits a button that should lead to any social network, like facebook, twitter etc., I want to check: is an app installed? If yes, open the app. If no, DON'T send the user to the Marketplace but open the browser with the site.

The code I have so far is just this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb://page/my_id"))
```

This opens the facebook-app if installed or sends me to the Marketplace otherwise.
The only alternative I have is this:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri((SocialMediaSelector.SelectedItem as SocialMediaViewModel).URL));
```

This just opens my facebook-page in IE.

Is there a way to know how many apps with a specific uri protocol are installed?

Comment: No, you cannot detect other applications on the phone.

Comment: I don't want to know much about them. Just hoped that there is some return-value like "yep, found something for 'fb'" or not, so I could react.

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't allowed. Probably some security constraint.

Comment: It's a consistent user experience the way it's handled today. An application shouldn't be able to probe the OS for other installed applications (which could be done by looking for unique handlers for example). You might have an app that "encourages" installation of a second application in place of something already installed.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying this. At least I can stop searching now.